# how to set yiiMongodbsuite unique field

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, yii-extensions

just wondering how can I set a field to be unique with YiiMongodbsuite?
I checked the YiiMongodbsuite documents and couldnt find anything related.

Answer (score 2):

Indexes (unique is index too) should be defined in `indexes` method, here is some sample [from docs](http://canni.github.com/YiiMongoDbSuite/xhtml_single/index.html#toc%3aadvanced_indexing):

```
class Client extends EMongoDocument
{
    public function indexes()
    {
        return array(
            // index name is not important, you may write whatever you want, just must be unique
            'index1_name'=>array(
                // key array holds list of fields for index
                // you may define multiple keys for index and multikey indexes
                // each key must have a sorting direction SORT_ASC or SORT_DESC
                'key'=>array(
                    'field_name'=>EMongoCriteria::SORT_ASC
                    'field_name.embeded_field'=>EMongoCriteria::SORT_DESC
                ),

                // unique, if indexed field must be unique, define a unique key
                'unique'=>true,
            ),
        );
    }
    // ....
}
```

Also check `UniqueValidator` in mongo db suite package for use with yii validators.